# Unexpected rbind behavior: No rows added in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, rbind

EDIT: 
I start with a mildly large data frame composed of around 4000 rows and 3 columns. the first column gives out a number the second a letter (which i'll call hospital name) and the third column is a state (2 letter abbreviation). I have to produce a data frame that displays the hospital name (2nd row) and its state, as the following (only 2 rows displayed):

```
         hospital state
    1      A      AK
    2      B      MD
```

What i need to achieve is a function that extracts the hospital ranking (lower better) and produces a dataframe with the hospital in the given position in that state, for all states.
I've written a simulation

```
sim<-data.frame(c(rnorm(4000, 2, 3)), sample(letters, size=4000, replace=T),          sample(ST, size=4000, replace=T ))

simrank<- function(letter="a", num=1) {

Srank<-data.frame()
set<-data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(ST)){
    Srank<-sim[sim[,3]==ST[i], c(1, 2)]
    Srank<-Srank[order(Srank[,1], Srank[,2], decreasing=F),]
    Srank<-cbind(Srank, c(1:length(Srank[,1])))
    Srank<-Srank[Srank[,3]==num, 2]
    newr<-c(Srank[2], ST[i])
    set<-rbind(set, newr)

}
colnames(set)<-(c("hospital", "state"))
set
}
```

I keep getting:

```
       hospital state
    1      <NA>    AK
    2      <NA>  <NA>
    3      <NA>  <NA>
```

the ST vector is:

```
    ST<-c("AK", "AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "DE", "FL", "GA", "GU", "HI", "IA", "ID", "IL", "IN", "KS", "KY", "LA", "MA", "MD", "ME", "MI", "MN", "MO", "MS", "MT", "NC" ,"ND", "NE", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NV", "NY", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "PR", "RI", "SC", "SD" ,"TN", "TX", "UT", "VA", "VI", "VT", "WA", "WI", "WV", "WY)
```

First post

My code goes:

```
Hrank<-data.frame()
set<-data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(ST)){
    Hrank<-dat[dat[,7]==ST[i], c(2, outcome)]                          #subset a larger data frame 
    Hrank<-Hrank[order(Hrank[,2], Hrank$Hospital.Name, decreasing=F),] #sort data frame
    Hrank<-cbind(Hrank, c(1:length(Hrank[,1])))                        #add a row that gives a rank
    Hrank<-Hrank[Hrank[,3]==num, 1]                                    #Subsets the data frame again
    str(Hrank) #just checking 
    newr<-c(Hrank[1], ST[i])                                           #create the vector to bind in data frame "set"
    str(newr)                                                          #just checking
    set<-rbind(set, newr) #bind in set by row. 

}
colnames(set)<-(c("hospital", "state"))

set
```

So, basically I was hoping a neat data frame out put for as many objects there where in my ST variable (in this case a 54x2 data frame). What I get:

```
    head(output)
                             hospital state
    1  MAT-SU REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    AK
    2                            <NA>  <NA>
    3                            <NA>  <NA>
    4                            <NA>  <NA>
    5                            <NA>  <NA>
    6                            <NA>  <NA>
```

also, the srt(newr) returns a character vector of 2 objects, as expected. I don't know whats happening and have actually no clue towards the solution. I can only suspect that the for loop has something to do with it but it's a wild guess.

Comment: I doubt that you should be using a `for` loop. However, your question is not reproducible as it is missing a small example of input data. It also doesn't show expected output and I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for that wrote it on a hurry, will edit. One sec please.

Comment: don't use `rbind` rather initialise an object and subset e.g. rows and store information in that row as you loop over the rows. thats much neater.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rbind things, they should be of similar types. Also, when adding rows to a data.frame, you must match up column names. So to get this example to work, you would need to initialize `set` with the right names

```
set<-data.frame(hospital=character(), state=character())
```

and then rather than

```
newr<-c(Hrank[1], ST[i])bind in data frame "set"
set<-rbind(set, newr) #bind in set by row.
```

you can do

```
set<-rbind(set, data.frame(hospital=Hrank[[1]], state=ST[i]))
```

Comment: Note that as other's have pointed out, adding a row at a time to a data.frame is a terrible idea. It would probably be better to be clear about how you are trying to subset the data.frame in the first place and we may be able to suggest a better strategy.

Comment: I'll try that out in a sec. Posted what i believe is a simulation of the error.

Comment: It seems that the problem desisted after changing workstations. Seems to be a system problem or a RStudio problem